# replace multiple characters at the same time jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

i'm trying to replace multiple character on this code but apparently it's not working the characters are:

A >> M

M >> A

as you see A must change to M and M must change to A and so on for the others

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
     var text = $("textarea").val();

text=text.replace(/A/g,'M');
text=text.replace(/[M_]/g,'A');
text=text.replace(/[T_]/g,'T');
text=text.replace(/[R_]/g,'E');
text=text.replace(/[I_]/g,'I');
text=text.replace(/[O_]/g,'R');
text=text.replace(/[V_]/g,'V');
text=text.replace(/[P_]/g,'O');
text=text.replace(/[U_]/g,'U');
text=text.replace(/[Z_]/g,'P');
text=text.replace(/[S_]/g,'S');
text=text.replace(/[X_]/g,'Z');
text=text.replace(/[K_]/g,'K');
text=text.replace(/[W_]/g,'X');
text=text.replace(/[Q_]/g,'Q');



text=text.replace(/[a_]/g,'m');
text=text.replace(/[m_]/g,'a');
text=text.replace(/[e_]/g,'t');
text=text.replace(/[t_]/g,'e');
text=text.replace(/[r_]/g,'i');
text=text.replace(/[i_]/g,'r');
text=text.replace(/[o_]/g,'v');
text=text.replace(/[v_]/g,'o');
text=text.replace(/[p_]/g,'u');
text=text.replace(/[u_]/g,'p');
text=text.replace(/[z_]/g,'s');
text=text.replace(/[s_]/g,'z');
text=text.replace(/[x_]/g,'k');
text=text.replace(/[k_]/g,'x');
text=text.replace(/[w_]/g,'q');
text=text.replace(/[q_]/g,'w');
text=text.replace(/[=_]/g,'/');
text=text.replace(/[@_]/g,'+');
text=text.replace(/[+_]/g,'@');



        $('p').html(text);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<textarea  name="paragraph_text" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button text="fsd">click me</button>


<p></p>
<html>
```

`
can you please tell me what's the problem only one or two character are replaced when i click the button,

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle link?

Comment: So you are changing all the A to M? Then all the M to A? So all your M and A will all be A. All the other characters will have the same problem. I suggest using a placeholder while swapping them out

Comment: oh yeah i see the problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, when you have code like this:

```
text=text.replace(/A/g,'M');
text=text.replace(/[M_]/g,'A');
```

...you first change the A's to M's, then immediately change them back again. Also this changes all of the underscore characters to A's, which means that in all of the following lines having underscores in the regexes like `[T_]` and `[R_]` is redundant because there are no underscores left to find.

Also lines like this:

```
text=text.replace(/[V_]/g,'V');
```

...don't do anything at all, because the replacement is the same character you're matching on (and as already mentioned there will be no underscores left at that point).

I'd suggest a different approach to the whole thing. You can use a single call to [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex that includes all of the characters you want to replace, and then instead of supplying a replacement string in `.replace()`'s second argument, supply a callback function that does the replacement based on a lookup table, perhaps a little something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var regex = /[_AMTRIOVPUZSXKWQametriovpuzsxkwq=@+]/g;
  var replacements = { '_': 'M', 'A': 'M', 'M': 'A', 'T': 'T', 'R': 'E', 'I': 'I', 'O': 'R', 'V': 'V', 'P': 'O', 'U': 'U', 'Z': 'P', 'S': 'S', 'X': 'Z', 'K': 'K', 'W': 'X', 'Q': 'Q', 'a': 'm', 'm': 'a', 'e': 't', 't': 'e', 'r': 'i', 'i': 'r', 'o': 'v', 'v': 'o', 'p': 'u', 'u': 'p', 'z': 's', 's': 'z', 'x': 'k', 'k': 'x', 'w': 'q', 'q': 'w', '=': '/', '@': '+', '+': '@' };

  $("button").click(function() {
    var text = $("textarea").val();
    text = text.replace(regex, function(match) { return replacements[match]; });
    $('p').html(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="paragraph_text" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button text="fsd">click me</button>
<p></p>
```

In case it's not obvious, the callback function is called once per match with the matched text as an argument, and the replacement value for that match is whatever the callback function returns.

Comment: IT WORKS THANK YOU A LOT